# Android custom Seekbar from drawable

Tags: android, user-interface, seekbar, android-seekbar

Could you please help me to draw custom Seekbar like shown in this picture -

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/volume_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_drawable"/>
```

seekbar_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_background" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress" />
</layer-list>
```

seekbar_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <gradient
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:centerY="0.5"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <clip>
            <bitmap
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/volume_empty"
                android:tileMode="repeat" />
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

seekbar_progress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:centerY="0.5"
                    android:endColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:startColor="@color/colorWhite" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/volume_empty"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

where @drawable/volume_empty is [volume_empty.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g70Ko.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution.

seekbar_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <gradient
                android:centerY="0.5"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <clip>
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_empty"
                android:tileMode="repeat" />
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

seekbar_progress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <clip>
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_full"
                android:tileMode="repeat" />
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_empty"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I've added similar transparent padding in both images, like ic_volume_empty - [ic_volume_empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXyf7.png) and ic_volume_full - [ic_volume_full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXUq6.png)